# Meaning of "...a few minutes out of a million..."

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Here is a sentence from an [article](http://www.bbc.com/news/blogs-news-from-elsewhere-28989520) on http://www.bbc.com/:

*The rocks also don't slide around very often - scientists estimate only a few minutes out of a million - which is why the event has not been noticed before.*

I think the word "minute"  refers here to the unit of angular measurement and not to the unit of time. However, I am still puzzled by the phrase "scientists estimate only a few minutes out of a million". What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

The phrase defines *not ... very often* more precisely:

> Scientists estimate *that the rocks slide around for* only a few minutes *during every* million *minutes*.

Comment: That is, "minute" is a unit of time here?

Comment: @Sinusx Exactly.

Comment: One million minutes is almost two years. The clue that 'minutes' means time and not angle is 'very often', which is a 'time' kind of word.

Answer (score 1):

It could be better worded, but *minutes* here is referring to the unit of time and not angles.

> The rocks also don't slide around very often - scientists estimate
>   *they are moving for* only a few minutes *a year* - which is why the event has not
>   been noticed before.

Using a million seconds is strange, especially as it's almost 2 years (1.9), which people can visualise much more easily.